# Change a font in Magento store

Tags: php, css, magento, fonts, magento-1.7

I am trying to find where to change the "New Products" font on the front page of my Magento store.  see- www.ethosdefense.com, scroll down to see the "New Products" section.  Notice the font is completely different from the other fonts.

If you use the browser dev tools, it shows that the formatting is from "(index):263".  Where do I change this code? It's NOT part of styles.css or index.php.  I cant find it anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

In the page, there's this section:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {background-color:ffffff;background-image:url(http://);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top left;background-attachment:fixed;}
    h1{font-family:Cursive;color:000000;}
    p {text-align:left;font-size:48px;font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;line-height:58px;color:FFFFFF;}
</style>
```

That's where `h1` is getting the Cursive font style from.

Comment: I cant find that file though...been scouring...It's being generated somehow.

Comment: I've looked at your page using dev tools in IE, Firefox, and Chrome.  From everything I can see, that style exists in index.php.  I'd look at whatever is assembling index.php, because it doesn't appear to be anything I can see via dev tools.  It's not in any of the .css files, it's not in any of the .js files.

Comment: Here is my entire index.php.  Can you tell me where I should poke around?
/**
 * Error reporting
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

/**
 * Compilation includes configuration file
 */
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {

Comment: echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}

require_once $mageFilename;

#Varien_Profiler::enable();

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);

/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ?

Comment: $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

Comment: There's a couple of files that I think are being pulled in, config.php and mage.php.  If that section isn't in one of those files, I'd recommend searching the project directory for a file that has the text `Cursive` in it.

Comment: thanks for your insight.  I've searched both of those files too. I thought of trying to search for "cursive" in the content of the files but dont know how.  Can you point me to the UX command that will tell me from an SSH terminal?

Comment: This link should help.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-finding-files-by-content/  The basic command you're looking for is `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an interesting problem here.

Richard's answers are helpful but remember your page content is being assembled by the Magento Frontend Controller so the way the layout is constructed is part of a large configuration tree, controlled by Magento and your theme.

Widen your inspection of the HTML around the `<style>` that Richard spotted:

```
<div id="camera_wrap" class="camera_wrap camera_ash_skin">

    <div data-link="http://www.ethosdefense.com/index.php/holsters.html/" data-src="http://www.ethosdefense.com/skin/frontend/default/theme490/images/camera/slides/slide1.jpg">&nbsp;
    </div>

    <div data-link="http://www.ethosdefense.com/index.php/armor.html/" data-src="http://www.ethosdefense.com/skin/frontend/default/theme490/images/camera/slides/slide2.jpg">&nbsp;
    </div>

    <div data-link="http://www.ethosdefense.com/index.php/knives.html/" data-src="http://www.ethosdefense.com/skin/frontend/default/theme490/images/camera/slides/slide3.jpg">&nbsp;
      <div class="camera_caption" class="fadeFromLeft">
        <style type="text/css">
          body {background-color:ffffff;background-image:url(http://);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top left;background-attachment:fixed;}
          h1{font-family:Cursive;color:000000;}
          p {text-align:left;font-size:48px;font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;line-height:58px;color:FFFFFF;}
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>"The only thing needed for the triumph of evil is for good men to do nothing"
        <br>-Edmund Burke</p>
        </body>
        </html>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This tells us a few things:

a) You are using [this theme](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/44770.html) (that's okay)

b) After the style declaration there are some spurious and incorrect `</head>...<body></body></html>` tags. That is very bad and sets off a few alarm bells. Whoever did this, this is not what they intended.

c) This section of HTML is something to do with a camera wrap and has three containing divs - one for holsters, one for armour and one for knives. It is the knives section that is problematic.

d) The spurious `<style></style>` **is not** controlling the font of the `<p>` content that you want to change. You probably already know this but I would use `font-family: 'Impact';` and I would use an inline style `<p style="font-family: 'Impact';">"The only thing needed...</p>`

I suspect that if you log into your Magento Admin and go to `CMS->pages` and find your home page content and edit it then you will find a widget that has these three 'cameras' and one of them will have the bad HTML in it. Alternatively you might find that your CMS home page contains a static block (`CMS->Static blocks`) where you can find the relevant static block and seek a widget or code there that is adding this very bad HTML to your page.

Then revoke the admin login of whoever put the bad code in.